# Search for and substitute SSL certificate in memory at run-time

Tags: debugging, ssl, reverse-engineering

I'm reverse-engineering a proprietary protocol in order to create a free and open client. By running the proprietary client program and watching traffic, I've so far mapped out most of the protocol. The authentication, though, is encrypted with SSL. It's my next target.

I know a common way forward is to route all traffic through a proxy under my control, essentially performing a man in the middle attack. For that reason, I need the program in question to accept my self-signed SSL certificate. Here's where I venture into unknown territory, though: The program is written in Adobe Flash and uses the AIR runtime. I have not been successful in locating the SSL fingerprint in the program files, and even if I could do this, I don't know anything about Flash and would probably screw something up when binary-patching the program. I'm thus left with the option of altering memory at run-time. Dumping the memory of the program confirms the existence of the signing authority's name in several places.

Does anyone know of a technique to automatically locate everything that looks like an SSL certificate in memory? Does anyone have any tips in general for me?

I use Linux, so I've so far been running the program under Wine and using GDB, as well as inspecting /proc/n/mem, but Windows-specific tips are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Validation of server-side certificates is usually done not by comparing certificate binaries (which you could substitute) but by performing complex analysis of the presented certificate. Consequently the easiest approach is to find the place where the final verdict on certificate validity is made (it will most likely be in AIR runtime rather than in the script) and patch that place.